# Turning Individual Sass or Stylus Components into a CSS File

Tags: css, sass, stylus

I am looking for a way to create individual component CSS files from libraries like Materialize CSS or Vuetify.

Materialize is written in Sass and Vuetify in Stylus.  I want to convert the various sass and stylus files into individual css files.

So, for instance, instead of the Materialize _button.scss, I'd like to create a button.css file with just the button related css.  Same thing goes for _cards.scss, _navbar.scss, etc.

I'd like to do the same thing for the stylus components in vuetify.

Does anyone know how to do this (either in Sass or in Stylus)?

For what it's worth -- I use VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

In VS Code, install the extension Live SASS Compiler, and enter the command in the VS Code Terminal :

```
sass --watch input.scss output.css

or if it is in folder, then

sass --watch scss/input.scss:css/output.css
```

This will automatically convert scss files to css files

Vote if it helps

Comment: It doesn't seem to compile them into individual files -- just one big file. Or am I doing something wrong?